# CAS clients over HTTP

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

I have installed CAS server and on the login screen I could see the below message when the client application is on HTTPS:

> HTTPS and IMAPS  This service definition authorized all application
>   urls that support HTTPS and IMAPS protocols.

But I need to enable HTTP client application. For this, when I change the client to HTTP, the login screen is showing the below error message:

> Application Not Authorized to Use CAS The application you attempted to
>   authenticate to is not authorized to use CAS.

Do you know how to enable CAS clients over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly depends on the CAS version and configuration. In the `deployerConfigContext.xml` file or in the JSON files (in `src/main/resources/services` directory), you should be able to set the `serviceId` to some regular expressions allowing HTTP, like `"serviceId" : "^https?://.*"`.
Each application allowed to login with CAS should have its own appropriate definition (in XML or JSON).